# How to get APNS device token using AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, apple-push-notifications, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

can anyone tell me the steps to get the APNS device token when using AWS Amplify?

From what I can tell, I need to get the device token, and then pass it to my backend so that we can create a PlatformApplicationArn in order to send a push notification to the devcie.

Answer (score 1):

for now AWS Amplify doesn't support push notifications.